Translational motion of a rigid body and summing angular momenta
I'm trying to understand the most accurate way to determine the angular momentum of a rigid body that is undergoing translational motion around a point. Perhaps I missed something in my classical mechanics course, but this type of motion seems somewhat problematic to me: on the one hand, it's translational, but on the other, it's rotational. I'd like to clarify the correct way to think about such situations.
The example that comes to mind is a Ferris wheel, where the cabins experience no friction at their mounts. For clarity, let's assume the cabins are fixed at their centers of mass and have symmetrical shapes. To abstract from gravity, we can consider a carousel with a vase that can also rotate. Both rotate about the same axis, but generally with different angular velocities $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$. The vase need not be symmetric. I believe the Ferris wheel example reduces to this more general case if we disregard potential energy.
The question that primarily interests me is: how do we correctly determine the angular momentum of the cabin or vase?
The most general and convincing method seems to be as follows:

Find the vector sum of the angular velocities.

Determine the position of the instantaneous axis of rotation.

Find the moment of inertia of the body relative to this axis.

Use these to calculate the angular momentum:
$L = I(\mathbf{\omega_1} + \mathbf{\omega_2})$


Another method involves finding the angular momentum relative to the axis and seems more suitable for coaxial rotations. In my examples:

Find the moment of inertia $I_0$ of the body relative to the axis of the Ferris wheel (or carousel).

Find the moment of inertia $I_A$ of the body relative to its own axis.

Calculate the angular momentum using
$L = I_0\omega_1 + I_A\omega_2$
(here $\omega_i$ are projections, not magnitudes).


The second method seems somewhat dubious and confusing to me. Firstly, it seems to only make sense for symmetric bodies; otherwise, the moments of inertia could change over time, which seems incredibly inconvenient. Secondly, the method only works for coaxial rotations. Thirdly, and most concerning, I couldn't obtain a correct expression for the kinetic energy of the vase in my second example using this method (I used the result provided by König's theorem as the correct one).
However, the first method, in turn, doesn't seem to provide an adequate answer to the question of the angular momentum of a Ferris wheel cabin. Since the angular velocities are equal, their sum is zero, and the ratio is $-1$, so the instantaneous axis doesn't exist. This result is somewhat undefined. The second method, on the other hand, gives a seemingly logical result: $m\omega r^2$ —- the angular momentum of the center of mass of a rigid body in translational motion.
I've somewhat lost the thread of these considerations and would greatly appreciate your guidance.
